# How to index out value of number in pandas Dataframe KeyError: False

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

So I am trying to index out a value after it has been filtered to append it to a list. So far here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arr_1 = np.array([7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 4])
arr_2 = np.array([5, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3])
arr_3 = np.array([1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 1])

dict_of_arrs = {
    'arr' : [arr_1, arr_2, arr_3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_of_arrs)

true_list = []
false_list = []
filt = df.arr.apply(lambda x: np.diff(x)>0)
for i in filt:
    for n in i:
        if n==True:
            true_list.append(df.arr[n])
        else:
            false_list.append(df.arr[n])
```

Though I get the error:

```
KeyError: False
```

I have also treid indexing by doing `df.arr[i][n]` instead but as expected that gives me the error:

```
IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 5 instead of 3
```

What I would like to do is filter out True or False as I already have, then I would like to append the orignal number of all the True values to `true_list` and the same with the False. So when I do `print(true_list)` the output is a list of lists, with each list having only the values where filt==True, and the same for false_list. Thank You.

EDIT:
The expect output should look something like:

`print(true_list)`

then the output being:

```
[ 6, 9, 4]
[ 8, 9, 10, 3]
[ 9, 4, 5]
```

Because in each list the filt is looking for if the following value is greater than the last value. Therefore those that are True, have their int value added to the true_list. For the false_list it would look like:

```
[ 1, 2]
[2]
[3, 1]
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do here, the same question was asked some time back. What is your expected output ?

Comment: I think it would go a long way if you show what is your expected output.  There are better ways to do this.

Comment: `np.diff` gives you a list of 5 `bool` values, whereas your original arrays have 6 `int`s.  How do you intend to match those index? It's rather unclear what you need.

Comment: @r.ook What I would like to do is find of the 5 bool values, which are true, and then append the int value for which the object is true to the list true_list. And i would like to do the same with false were I find the bool values that are false and append their correlated int value to the list false_list. Thank you for responding

Comment: @Sushanth look at my comment above, tell me if more clarification is needed. Thank you for responding.

Comment: @r.ook then i ment of the 5 bool values, I would like to do what I mentioned above, yes I do know what diff does, sorry that was a typo to say 6.

Comment: Then please read my comment again.  How do you intend to match 6 `int`s to 5 `bool`s? Again, it would help if you could [edit] your question to show what is your expected end result.  We want to help you, but you have to help us help you.

Comment: Well then to be honest I dont know how to match that. Is there a better way to do this other than doing diff then? Do you have a way to match the bool values? This is the reason I asked this because I dont know how to procced.

Comment: @benito.cano Given this data, what do you want to the output to be?  Add Expected Output then what you want at the end of this post.

Comment: @Scott Bosotn As I had said before,  What I would like to do is find of the 5 bool values, which are true, and then append the int value for which the object is true to the list true_list. And i would like to do the same with false were I find the bool values that are false and append their correlated int value to the list false_list. Is this what you are asking by output or how else to explain what I would like? Thank you for responding

Comment: Please modify you question with the format of the list, shape of the object etc..

Comment: ... Let's keep it simple and minimize the *sub problem*.  Say you have `[7, 1, 6]`, and `[True, False]`.  What do you want to see for `true_list`? `[7]`? `[7, 1]`? `[1]`? What about `false_list`? `[1]`? `[1, 6]`? `[6]`? Even if you answer this part of the question, it's still very unclear what is your end goal.  This is why we ask you to simply provide your *expected output* in the question.  Please see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Again thank you all for responding, I have tried to answer you questions in the edit to the question.

Comment: ..a....., . ..,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is same as [@Scott Boston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62227599/12416453) but without using `groupby` and `explode`.

Using [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and boolean indexing.

```
import numpy as np

df.arr.map(lambda x:np.array(x)[1:][np.diff(x)>=0])
0        [6, 9, 4]
1    [8, 9, 10, 3]
2        [9, 4, 5]
Name: arr, dtype: object

df.arr.map(lambda x:np.array(x)[1:][np.diff(x)<0])
0    [1, 2]
1       [2]
2    [3, 1]
Name: arr, dtype: object
```

`timeit` results:

```
In [63]: %%timeit
    ...: dfe = df['arr'].explode()
    ...: grp = dfe.groupby(level=0).diff()
    ...: df_g = dfe[grp >= 0]
    ...: df_increasing = df_g.groupby(level=0).agg(list)
    ...: 
    ...: df_l = dfe[grp < 0]
    ...: df_decreasing = df_l.groupby(level=0).agg(list)
    ...:
    ...:
7.16 ms ± 565 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [65]: %%timeit
    ...: df_x = df.arr.map(lambda x:np.array(x)[1:][np.diff(x)>=0])
    ...: df_y =df.arr.map(lambda x:np.array(x)[1:][np.diff(x)<0])
    ...:
    ...:
384 µs ± 5.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's see if this helps any:

```
dfe = df['arr'].explode()
grp = dfe.groupby(level=0).diff()
df_g = dfe[grp >= 0]
df_increasing = df_g.groupby(level=0).agg(list)

df_l = dfe[grp < 0]
df_decreasing = df_l.groupby(level=0).agg(list)

print(df_increasing)

# 0        [6, 9, 4]
# 1    [8, 9, 10, 3]
# 2        [9, 4, 5]
# Name: arr, dtype: object

print(df_decreasing)

# 0    [1, 2]
# 1       [2]
# 2    [3, 1]
# Name: arr, dtype: object
```

Comment: Neat, I was stuck on just using `gt` and didn't think to just do `lt` the other way around to filter out that false positive.  The first condition should be `> 0` though based on the requirement :)

Comment: `df_increasing = dfe.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x:x[x.diff().ge(0)].tolist())` reduces the usage of `groupby` repeatedly. Nice answer+1